# Laravel 5.4 Show flash error and success messages in different ways

Tags: laravel

Method from my PostController

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
    {
        if (Post::create($request->all())) {
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Post was successfully added!');
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Error!');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

index view

```
<?php if(session()->has('status')){
        echo '<div style="text-align: center">';
        echo session()->get('status');
        echo '</div>';
    }?>
```

How to show error and success messages in different ways?

Answer (score 23):

You can use something like this:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request) {
    if (Post::create($request->all())) {
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'success');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'Post was successfully added!');
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'danger');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'Error!');
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

In your blade file:

```
@if(session()->has('message.level'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message.level') }}"> 
    {!! session('message.content') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

The code above uses [bootstrap's alert css classes](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp) for styling and is inspired by [Jeffrey Way's Laracasts Flash package](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)

Comment: Very very very nice answer for me, thanks a lot mr. paras

Answer (score 15):

You can display flash messages in this way:

In your controller:

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Record successfully added!');
//OR
$request->session()->flash('warning', 'Record not added!');
```

In your veiw:

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $key)
 @if(Session::has($key))
     <p class="alert alert-{{ $key }}">{{ Session::get($key) }}</p>
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Write code like this in your Controller:

> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
>     
> Session::flash('error', 'Some thing is wrong. Please try again');
> Redirect::to(path to blade file route);
> ```

2. Write code like this in your Blade template:

> ```
> @if(Session::has('error'))
>         <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('error') }}</p>
> @endif
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->with()` in your controller

```
public function store(PostRequest $request) {
    if (!Post::create($request->all())) {
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Error!');
    }

    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Post was successfully added!');
}
```

Your view could look like this:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

or (with additional CSS for `alert-error` class):

```
@foreach (['error', 'success'] as $status)
    @if(Session::has($status))
        <p class="alert alert-{{$status}}">{{ Session::get($status) }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```