# I have a problem with session flash on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

First I show you my lines codes where I use `session::flash` to put instant messages. I work using the Laravel framework in php.

```
public function destroy($id){

  $city = CityNew::find($id);

  try {

    $city->delete();

  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

      Session::flash('message', 'There was an error');
      return redirect()->back(); 
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'It is ok');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My doubt is how can I use `session::flash` to show the message in red color? Now the inside the `cath()` the message appears in green color, If is not possible I would like to know which is the way that I can put another type of message, using everytime `session::flash`. Thanks!

Comment: Add some css class in your view to display in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the "type" of message in your backend

```
Session::flash('error', 'There was an error');

Session::flash('success', 'It is ok');
```

Then in your view, display accordingly

```
 @if(Session::has('error'))
     <span class="error">{{ Session::pull('error') }}</span>
 @endif

 @if(Session::has('success'))
     <span class="success">{{ Session::pull('success') }}</span>
 @endif
```

And in the css, you can add the color:

```
.error { color: red }
.success { color: green }
```

Of course, this is just an example. You may want to use some css library like Bootstrap, Bulma, ...

Comment: Thanks! Is very useful your answer. But, in this case, I don't use bootstrap I use `<style></style>` in the same page where i declared `@if`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959528/7377984) to style flash messages with various levels using Bootstrap